# SSRS Expression to Open Specific Report

Tags: image, reporting-services, conditional-statements, expression, iif

I have a SSRS dashboard that has a calender image on it and under the image properties I have an action to Go to Report and a specific report was listed.  Depending on the measure the user is looking at in the dashboard when they click it a 12 or 24 month trend chart will load.  It works fine when I just have it set to go to a specific report but when I put an expression into the Specify a Report option I get a weird error that I have been researching but the error seems possibly misleading so I thought I would just put the expression I am using out here to see if anyone has any direction for me as it seems like what I am trying to do is simple but I may be searching wrong.  Thanks in advance!

I have the expression opening the 24 month chart of the definition type is CSH and eventually it will check for other conditions but I wanted one to work before I went on.

=IIF(Fields!MEAS_DEFINITION_TYPE = "CSH","FITDash_Trend24mo.rdl",Nothing)

I get this error and it started up after I added the expression above.  The datatype of MEAS_DEFINTION_TYPE is nvarchar(25):

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       [rsCompilerErrorInExpression] The ActionInfo.Action.Drillthrough.ReportName expression for the image 'Calendar25' contains an error: [BC30311] Value of type 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportObjectModel.Field' cannot be converted to 'String'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common mistake, you have forgotten to specify the `.Value` property of the field

Try

```
=IIF(Fields!MEAS_DEFINITION_TYPE.Value = "CSH","FITDash_Trend24mo.rdl",Nothing)
```

Comment: Funny that is all I was forgetting. I had to laugh at myself for that. Learning can be funny lol.

Comment: remove the `.rdl`. Just use the report name

Comment: Thanks Alan that helped too!